# Redirect page if I hit back button, in the web browser?

Tags: javascript

I have an "Exam form" in PAGE A, that if submitted writes data into the database, and then redirect to PAGE B.

My problem is that, if I hit back button in PAGE B. It goes back to PAGE A, where I can again submit form and it again writes into the database.

**What is the best method to block this back button issue ?**

**Could I redirect to some other page ?**

I am looking for javascript method or php based solution is would be better. SQL based solution is messy.

Note: In SQL database, Primary key is an autogenerated id. I am using a general method save(), to write all data into the db. which basicaly collect all data from the form make it into an object and write it into db. Its a general method that I use in many other forms in the project. I would like to not touch that.

*I tried fetching 'apno' & 'qid' from database and compare it while posting second time.*

```
<?php
$j = 1;
foreach ($allquestions as $questions)
{
    if (is_post_request())
    {
        $args = $_POST['answers' . $j];
        $check_if_submited = Answers::find_by_objapno($apno);
        foreach ($args as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($key == "qid")
            {
                $qid = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($check_if_submited->apno == $apno && $check_if_submited->qid == $qid)
        {
            $session->message('Not Saved. Exam Already Taken.');
            redirect_to(url_for('/user/student/showexams.php?id=' . $sid));
        }
        else
        {
            $answers = new Answers($args);
            $result = $answers->save();
            if ($result === true)
            {
                $answers->aid_create();
                if ($j < $qcount)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    $session->message($j . ' Answers Saved.');
                    redirect_to(url_for('/user/student/showexams.php?id=' . $sid));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $answers = new Answers;
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

qid is not primary key. db could have multiple qid.

Comment: you can solve this if you follow SOLID principles. like applying the single responsibility principle, interface segregation.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          var hashLocation = location.hash;
          var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
          var hashName = hashSplit[1];

          if (hashName !== '') {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            if (hash === '') {
              alert('Back button was pressed.');
                window.location='www.example.com';
                return false;
            }
          }
        });

        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
      }

    });
```